# Show that this semimartingale is a local martingale

Tags: brownian-motion, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $B_t$ be a standard Wiener motion, $I_t=\int_0^t|B_s|^2\!\text{ds}\ $and $S_t=\max_{0\leq s\leq t}B_s$. Let also $F:\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a $C^{1,2,1}$ function.

Show that if:$$F_t(t,a,x,s)+x^2F_a(t,a,x,s)+\frac{1}{2}F_{xx}(t,a,x,s)=0$$ for every $(t,a,x,s)\in\mathbb{R}^2_+\times\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}_+$ and $F_s(t,a,x,s)=0$ for $x=s$,

then $F(t,I_t,B_t,S_t)$ is a continuous local martingale for $t\geq0$.

What I have done:

Since $I_t$ and $S_t$ are increasing processes $\Longrightarrow\ I_t, S_t$ are processes of bounded variation. Hence, we can apply Ito's formula. We have that:

$F(t,I_t,B_t,S_t)=F(0,I_0,B_0,S_0)+\int_0^tF_t(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{dr}+\int_0^tF_a(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}I_r+\\
+\int_0^tF_x(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}B_r+\int_0^tF_s(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}S_r+
\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tF_{xx}(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}\left<B,B\right>_r=\\$

$=F(0,I_0,B_0,S_0)+\int_0^tF_t(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{dr}
+\int_0^tF_a(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}I_r+\\
+\int_0^tF_x(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}B_r+\int_0^tF_s(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}S_r
+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tF_{xx}(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{dr}$

In order to show that $F(t,I_t,B_t,S_t)$ is a continuous local martingale, we need to show that:

$\int_0^tF_t(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{dr}+
\int_0^tF_a(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}I_r+\int_0^tF_s(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}S_r+\\
+\frac{1}{2}\int_0^tF_{xx}(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{dr}=0$

What can we do with the terms $\int_0^tF_s(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}S_r$ and $\int_0^tF_a(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}I_r$? How will we relate them to the given relation?

Comment: First hint: $dI_r = |B_r|^2 dr$.

Comment: OK, since $I_r=\int_0^r|B_s|^2\text{d}s\ \Longrightarrow\ \text{d}I_r=|B_r|^2\text{d}r$ and this is the term $x^2F_a(t,a,x,s)$ that we have in the given relation.

If $S_r=B_r\ \Longrightarrow\ \max_{0\leq s\leq r}B_s=B_r\ \Longrightarrow\ B_r\geq B_s$ for every $s\in[0,r]$ and this is my only conclusion! I need a second hint! :)

Comment: Is this an exercise from a book...?

Comment: It is an exercise from a class. A friend of mine has given me his notes from the class and I came across this exercise which I cannot find a way to solve it!

Comment: We have that $M_t=c+\int_0^tH_s\text{d}B_s$ for some process $H$. Then $\text{d}M_t=H_t\text{d}B_t$. Isn't that right?

Comment: @NickPapadopoulos Probably you mean $S_t$ instead of $M_t$...? And why should there exist such a process $H$? If you apply the martingale representation theorem, you obtain the existence of a process $(s,\omega) \mapsto H^t(s,\omega)$ such that $S_t = c+ \int_0^t H^t(s) \, dB_s$. But the process $H^t$ depends on $t$!

Comment: I suspect that there is a typo in this exercise, $F_s(t,a,x,s) = 0$ for all $x \leq s$ instead of $x=s$.

Comment: Yes, I meant $S_t$! Thanks. I thought that the process $H$ does not depend on $t$... If it is $x\leq s$, then we always have that $S_t=\max_{0\leq s\leq t}B_s\geq B_t$ and the exercise is trivial.

Comment: $H$ would not depend on $t$ if $(S_t)_t$ is a martingale... (and no, it's not trivial... we do not claim $F(t,a,x,s) = 0$, but $F_s(t,a,x,s)=0$ for $x \leq s$).

Comment: But, if $F_s(t,a,x,s)=0$, then $\int_0^tF_s(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}S_r=0$ and together with the other given relations, we have that $F(t,I_t,B_t,S_t)=F(0,I_0,B_0,S_0)+\int_0^tF(r,I_r,B_r,S_r)\text{d}B_r$ which is a continuous local martingale

Comment: Ah okay, that's what you meant by "trivial". Yes, that's correct... (Perhaps it would be a good idea to ask the teacher of the class - probably he has solutions for all his exercises...)

Comment: Yes, I meant trivial, given that we have done all the work above!